# Script to do Windows Update on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, automation, windows-update

Is there any batch script or command line command that can do Windows Update automatically on multiple remote servers (maybe via psexec)? Not prefer using a VB script, but if there's one available, that's fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to do.  If you want a more batch-style, psexec method, you need to look into a shareware CLI utility I have seen before.  To be honest, I have never tested it myself, [wuinstall](http://wuinstall.com/).  I see some articles from Windows-type IT mags, so I doubt you will be the first guy.  There is a freeware and pro version, but I cannot say what the licensing restrictions are.

If you can get over the scripting, I know this Winboxen sysadmin lucifist wrote a PowerShell script to do [what you are looking for.](http://lucifist.mobile.spaces.live.com/entry.aspx?h=cns!EE1D58B49769505A!192&fp=%2ftop.aspx)

```
######################################################################################################################################
# Windows Update through Powershell (No Forms) v1.0 ######################################################################################################################################
clear-host
Write-host "Starting Update Process..." -foregroundcolor blue
Write-host ""
$UpdateSession = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.Session 
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher() 
$SearchResult =  $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0")
$UpdateLowNumber = 0 
$UpdateHighNumber = 1 
$NumberofUpdates = $searchResult.Updates.Count


while ($UpdateHighNumber -le $NumberofUpdates) {
$UpdatesToDownload = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl 
$Update = $searchResult.Updates.Item($UpdateLowNumber) 


if ($Update.EulaAccepted -eq 0) {$Update.AcceptEula()} 


[void]$UpdatesToDownload.Add($Update)
$Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
$Downloader.Updates = $UpdatesToDownload 
[void]$Downloader.Download()


$UpdatesToInstall = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl 
[void]$UpdatesToInstall.Add($Update)


$Title = $update.Title 
$KBArticleIDs = $update.KBArticleIDs
$SecurityBulletinIDs = $update.SecurityBulletinIDs
$MsrcSeverity = $update.MsrcSeverity
$LastDeploymentChangeTime = $update.LastDeploymentChangeTime
$MoreInfoUrls = $update.MoreInfoUrls


Write-host "Installing Update $UpdateHighNumber of $NumberofUpdates"
Write-host "Title: $Title"
if ($KBArticleIDs -ne "") {Write-host "KBID: $KBArticleIDs"}
if ($SecurityBulletinIDs -ne "") {write-host "Security Bulletin: $SecurityBulletinIDs"}
if ($MsrcSeverity -eq "Critical") {Write-host "Rating: $MsrcSeverity" -foregroundcolor red} else {Write-host "Rating: $MsrcSeverity"}
if ($LastDeploymentChangeTime -ne "") {Write-host "Dated: $LastDeploymentChangeTime"}
if ($MoreInfoUrls -ne "") {Write-host "$MoreInfoUrls"}


$Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller() 
$Installer.Updates = $UpdatesToInstall 
$InstallationResult = $Installer.Install()
Write-host "--------------------------------------------"
if ($InstallationResult.ResultCode -eq "2") {Write-host "  Installation Succeeded" -foregroundcolor green}  else {Write-host "  INSTALLATION FAILED, check event log for details" -foregroundcolor red}
if ($InstallationResult.RebootRequired -eq "False") {Write-host "  Reboot not required" -foregroundcolor green} else {Write-host "  REBOOT REQUIRED" -foregroundcolor red}
Write-host "--------------------------------------------"
Write-host ""
Write-host ""


$Title = ""
$KBArticleIDs =  ""
$SecurityBulletinIDs =  ""
$MsrcSeverity =  ""
$LastDeploymentChangeTime =  ""
$MoreInfoUrls =  ""


$UpdateLowNumber = $UpdateLowNumber + 1 
$UpdateHighNumber = $UpdateHighNumber + 1


if ($ProgressValue -lt $NumberofUpdates) {$ProgressValue = $ProgressValue + 1} 
} 


$ComputerStatus = New-Object -com Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo
 if ($ComputerStatus.RebootRequired -eq 1) {cmd /c $env:WinDir\System32\Shutdown.exe -r -f -t 10 -c "Patching Complete."}
```

If you pay attention to this script, you will see you are opening up COM objects and such.  So, you either need to bake your own binary or someone else's non-MSFT code (a la Wuinstall), or do the same amount of scripting in VBScript.  You say Win23k Server, so I am not sure whether or not you have PS installed.  If not, there is [TechNet documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28VS.85%29.aspx) to cure your ills.

Bottom line, Google is your friend.  Keep that in mind before posting here.  :-)

Comment: Posting questions here makes Google a better friend for other people later on. There are no bad questions, per se.

Comment: Oh, totally agree.  I was just pointing out that I had found all of this on Google.  And to be fair, knowing the exact phrase to use is more important than knowing its omnipotence.  :-)